# jQuery - Set only empty value to 0

Tags: jquery

Below code is used to check if input value is empty, change value to `0`. But it also makes input value which is `non-zero`

```
<input type="text" value="8" class="input-mini txt">
<input type="text" value="8" class="input-mini txt">
<input type="text" value="0" class="input-mini txt">
<input type="text" value="0" class="input-mini txt">


    $("input.input-mini.txt").each(function () {
        var hours = $.trim($(this).val());
          if(!hours){
              $("input.input-mini.txt").prop("value",0)
          }
    });
```

How to set value `0` only for those inputs which are `empty/null` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` within the callback, and use `val`, not `prop`:

```
$("input.input-mini.txt").each(function () {
    var hours = $.trim($(this).val());
    if(!hours){
      $(this).val(0);
    }
});
```

`!hours` is fine, because the value you're testing will always be a string, and `!"0"` is false but `!""` is true.

Note: Although I've written `0`, not `"0"`, in the above, the value of `input type=text` fields is *always* a string, and so it will get coerced.

Comment: T.J.Crowder: Thanks for the explaination too..:)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `jQuery.isEmptyObject(object);` to check if object is empty
e.g

```
$("input.input-mini.txt").each(function () {
    var obj.hours = $.trim($(this).val());
      if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(obj)){
        $(this).val(0);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Now it will fail in two ways: 1) It will try to set a property on `undefined`, which will throw an exception, and 2) Even if that didn't happen, you've **guaranteed** that `isEmptyObject` will return `false` now (because you've created an enumerable property on the object). You're using a chainsaw to drive a nail; it's completely and utterly the wrong tool.